# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

### Description of the problem:

Trying to import JSON file when server starts up.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    Videos = fs.readFileSync("public/toc_vd_en.json", "utf8");
  });
}
```

Getting a `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'public/toc_vd_en.json'`

**File structure:**

[image: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory]

### Question:

I believe I'm giving the correct relative path. What is causing this error?

Comment: Try `/public/toc_vd_en.json`

Comment: That already crossed my mind. Still getting the same error. **Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/public/toc_vd_en.json'**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mate, try this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    var base = process.env.PWD;
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    Videos = fs.readFileSync(base + "/public/toc_vd_en.json", "utf8");
  });
}
```

Comment: Already crossed my mind as well. **{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'public/toc_vd_en.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'public/toc_vd_en.json' }**

Comment: @try put the toc_vd_en.json under the same level of your main js file, and try readFile('toc_vd_en.json'), if that does not even work , then you see the problem

Comment: I actually just thought of that and gave it a try. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @KФ, you know what, bro, i suspect your extension..., check do you have a hidden txt file extension or something like that

Comment: @KФ, use this to get your absolute root directory path, var base = process.env.PWD, then just put your json file on the root level, and give it a try

Comment: That was it! Nice. The relative path just wasn't good I suppose. Which I find really awkward. **https://gist.github.com/awatson1978/4625493**. Update your answer and I'll mark it as right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Videos = fs.readFileSync("public/toc_vd_en.json", "utf8");
```

change to

```
Videos = fs.readFileSync("../public/toc_vd_en.json", "utf8");
```