# fs.readFileSync() function doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, meteor

The following code doesn't work as expected:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;

var server = PeerServer({
port: 9000,
path: '/peerjs',
ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../certificates/key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../certificates/cert.pem', 'utf8')
}
});
```

It returns the following error:

> /Users/mzn/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.i59qpv.ylxp8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280 W20180606-15:08:29.566(4)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
>   W20180606-15:08:29.566(4)? (STDERR)                       ^ W20180606-15:08:29.566(4)?
>
> (STDERR)  W20180606-15:08:29.567(4)? (STDERR) Error: ENOENT: no such
>
> file or directory, open '../certificates/key.pem'
>
> W20180606-15:08:29.567(4)? (STDERR)     at Object.fs.openSync
>   (fs.js:646:18) W20180606-15:08:29.567(4)? (STDERR)     at
>
> Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33) W20180606-15:08:29.568(4)?
>
> (STDERR)     at main.js (chat/server/main.js:15:11)
>
> W20180606-15:08:29.568(4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate
>
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9) W20180606-15:08:29.568(4)?
>
> (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
>
> W20180606-15:08:29.569(4)? (STDERR)     at
>
> /Users/mzn/Desktop/All/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:537:1
>
> W20180606-15:08:29.569(4)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info
>
> (/Users/mzn/Desktop/All/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)

Below is the structure of my files

[image: file structure]

I am using `fs.readFileSync('../certificates/key.pem', 'utf8')` inside `main.js`

I tried the solutions [posted here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261) but it did not solve it for me.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    var base = process.env.PWD;
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;


    var server = PeerServer({
        port: 9000,
        path: '/peerjs',
        ssl: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(base + '/chat/certificates/key.pem', 'utf8'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(base + '/chat/certificates/cert.pem', 'utf8')
        }
    });
});
}
```

Credit to @Kevin Simple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733331/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-in-meteor).

Hope it will solve it for you

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [`fs` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths),

> String form paths are interpreted as UTF-8 character sequences identifying the absolute or relative filename. Relative paths will be resolved relative to the current working directory as specified by process.cwd().

The error means that current working directory isn't a directory where main.js is located, `chat/server`.

If paths to these files should be resolved from current module path, it should be:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../certificates/key.pem'), 'utf8')
```